# How to get a package from its path in Java

Tags: java, java-8, package, java-17

I use the `Package.getpackage(String)` method to get a Package from its path in Java. To test the method, I have the following very simple code:

```
   public static void main(String[] args) {
      Package pack = Package.getPackage("java.lang");
      System.out.println(pack);
      pack = Package.getPackage("java.util");
      System.out.println(pack);      
      pack = Package.getPackage("java.util.prefs");
      System.out.println(pack);      
      pack = Package.getPackage("java.util.regex");
      System.out.println(pack);            
      pack = Package.getPackage("java.util.zip");
      System.out.println(pack);      
      pack = Package.getPackage("java.awt");
      System.out.println(pack);  
   }
```

I have the following results with Java 8:

```
package java.lang, Java Platform API Specification, version 1.8
package java.util, Java Platform API Specification, version 1.8
null
null
package java.util.zip, Java Platform API Specification, version 1.8
null
```

And the same results with Java 17. The method is declared deprecated in the Java 17 API, and they propose to use instead the `ClassLoader.getDefinedPackage(String)` method.

Bu when I try it with this code on Java 17:

```
public class TestPackage2 {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
      ClassLoader loader = TestPackage2.class.getClassLoader();
      Package pack = getPackage(loader, "java.awt");
      System.out.println(pack);
   }

       private static Package getPackage(ClassLoader loader, String path) {
          Package pack = null;
          while (true) {
             pack = loader.getDefinedPackage(path);
             if (pack != null) {
                break;
             } else {
                loader = loader.getParent();
                if (loader == null) {
                   break;
                }
             }         
          }
          return pack;
       }
    }
```

I have a `null` result.

My questions are:

- Why is it not working even when I'm using the "correct" way to do it in Java 17?
- Why is it not working even with a minimalistic example in Java 8 (not delegating ClassLoaders)?
- Is there a more reliable way to do it in both Java 8 and Java 17?

Comment: You might also need to check the package of the parent `ClassLoader`s (recursively).

Comment: Hello,it does not change the result (in Java 17, because I can't do that in Java 8 of course). I explained this in the description of my problem

Comment: Did you do it recursively using `ClassLoader#getParent`? If so, can you show the code where you did that?

Comment: `java.lang` will always be defined by the bootstrap loader which is represented by `null`, so there is no way to access it by calling `getDefinedPackage` on a class loader instance. It’s also worth noting that everything said in the explanation to why the `getPackage` method has been deprecated does not apply to the specific package `java.lang`.

Comment: OK, I updated the example, and used java.awt instead, but I still have a null result. See my updated explanation

Comment: It doesn’t matter as what I said applies to all packages starting with `java.` (and there might be more packages defined by the bootstrap loader). My comment was not meant to say that you’re doing something wrong. You tripped over a scenario where the deprecated method is the only working approach. Though I do not get “the same results with Java 17” as the `Package` instances have no meta information (title, etc) in Java 9 or newer. Which makes it unnecessary to get them in the first place.

Comment: ah ok. I understand now.